# How can I remove duplicated from my code in Java?

Tags: java, automated-tests

I wrote a test that will run recursion Fibonacci for 40 and run memoization recursion Fibonacci for 40 and compare the time to be at least one order of magnitude different. This is what I get so far:

```
      @Test
  void MemoizedMagnitudeDifferentFromRecursion(){
    Fibonacci simpleRecursiveFibonacci = new SimpleRecursiveFibonacci();
    Fibonacci memoizedRecursiveFibonacci = new MemoizedRecursiveFibonacci();
    int n = 40;

    long recursionStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    simpleRecursiveFibonacci.fibonacci(n);
    long recursionTime = System.nanoTime() - recursionStartTime;

//The code below does the same as the code above, how can I remove duplicated code?
    long memoizedStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    memoizedRecursiveFibonacci.fibonacci(n);
    long memoizedTime = System.nanoTime() - memoizedStartTime;

    assertTrue(recursionTime/memoizedTime > 1);
  }
```

Comment: Refactor it into a function.

Comment: What is the problem?  What do you want to remove?  Your DRY instinct is good, but I would say it's misplaced here.  It's a test, not runtime.  You'd move this into an aspect if it were a runtime issue.

Comment: Repeating a similar code only twice is not necessarily bad. Your code is ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the logic to a function and pass the logic to be run as a `Runnable`. Let the function run the piece of logic passed in and return the time it took to run it.

```
private long execute(Runnable runnable) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    runnable.run();
    return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

Call it as

```
long recursionTime = execute(() -> simpleRecursiveFibonacci.fibonacci(n));
long memoizedTime = execute(() -> memoizedRecursiveFibonacci.fibonacci(n));
assertTrue(recursionTime/memoizedTime > 1);
```

---

One more option (as suggested by SystemGlitch@) is to pass an instance of `Fibonacci` and an int and call `fibonacci` inside the method.

```
private long execute(Fibonacci fibonacciInstance, int n) {        
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    fibonacciInstance.fibonacci(n);
    return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

Call it as

```
long recursionTime = execute(simpleRecursiveFibonacci, n);
long memoizedTime = execute(memoizedRecursiveFibonacci, n);
assertTrue(recursionTime/memoizedTime > 1);
```

Comment: Nice use of lambda.

Comment: The function can be even simpler: pass a Fibonnaci as parameter and an int for the amount of iterations and execute fibonacci directly. However your approach makes it compatible with any other time test.

Comment: @SystemGlitch Thanks. I have added this to my answer.